# c# Datatable to List to loadgrammer

Tags: c#, database, voice-recognition

I'm trying to load data from a table into a list and after I try to use this list for inputting my grammar into speech recognition grammar.

Now the program just stops (without any error) before the code block where I try to load the list into the grammar.

Now I also integrated a richtextbox to show check that the list stays empty, and it is like this. So probably something goes wrong in my query but I can't find out what.

```
    List<String> lst = new List<string>();

    private void searchDB()
    {
       
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|/jarvisBrain.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Word FROM ImportedWordList",connection))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lst.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
          
            richTextBox1.Lines = lst.ToArray();

            connection.Close();
        }}
        //code stops here!!
     try
        {
            rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            
            rec.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(lst.ToArray()))));
            rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
            rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // sets to earplugs of speakers
            rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            // Set the speaking rate and volume
            s.Rate = 0;
            s.Volume = 100;
        }
```

Does anybody see the problem?

Comment: do you know how to use the `Debugger..` should the `try` be inside the method or outside..?

Comment: also when inside the loop, why don't you change this line `richTextBox1.Lines = lst.ToArray();` to `richTextBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0} {1}", reader["Word"].ToString(), Environment.NewLine));`

Answer (score 0):

Try the edit here looks like your issue is putting the code outside of the `searchDB` method

```
List<String> lst = new List<string>();

private void searchDB()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|/jarvisBrain.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Word FROM ImportedWordList",connection))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lst.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        richTextBox1.Lines = lst.ToArray();
        connection.Close();
    }
    //code stops here!!
    try
    {
        rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        rec.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(lst.ToArray()))));
        rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
        rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // sets to earplugs of speakers
        rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        // Set the speaking rate and volume
        s.Rate = 0;
        s.Volume = 100;
    }
}
```

where is your `catch(Exception ex) { }` block..?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code. with some more research and help from other people!

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = D:\VisualStudio\Projects\runSheet\frontPage_V1.1\Jarvis\Jarvis\Jarvis\jarvisBrain.mdf; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Word FROM ImportedWordList WHERE Word IS NOT NULL", connection))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {  
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    lst.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            richTextBox1.Lines = lst.ToArray();
            connection.Close();
        }
        //code stops here!!
        try
        {
            rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            rec.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(lst.ToArray()))));
            rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
            rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // sets to earplugs of speakers
            rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            // Set the speaking rate and volume
            s.Rate = 0;
            s.Volume = 100;
        }

catch { return; }
```